# VS2013 - Msbuild fails Error MSB3086: Could not find AL.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, windows-10

I've recently upgraded to Windows 10 and i've stumbled upon an error when trying to build my solution in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

The error is as follows:

```
Error   1   Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed    Common.Resources
```

So the one thing that came to mind is to download / install the Windows 8.1 & 10 SDK, this didn't solve this issue however. The error is referring to Microsoft SDK v8.1a; Shouldn't it refer to v10.0?
So I opened up regedit and looked at the key location and the v10.0 folder is missing and the v8.1a folder is empty.

There are a couple of keys that when created should fix this error, i've tried creating them manually aswell but this didn't fix it either.

So, I tried changing the sdk toolset, there's supposed to be a option I should be able to change, so I opened the **solution properties** > **Configuration Properties** > **Changed Configuration to 'All Configurations'.** and the **General** node appeared to be missing...

All of this happened after upgrading to windows 10, it messed up the sdk toolset somehow, i've done alot of research for this problem and I couldn't find a proper solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong registry key, VS is a 32-bit program and therefore uses the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A registry key.  It should not be empty.  Recovering from a corrupted registry is in general a fairly lost cause of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem; I decided to remove all the intalled SDKs then reinstall the latest Windows 10 SDK. Then I cleaned my solution and it built succesfully afterwards!